# Send message over Socket.IO to all followers

Tags: node.js, swift, socket.io

I have implemented a socket.io connection in my Swift app. I run a node.js server on the backend. I am now able to emit messages to a specific user, like this:

```
let connectedClients = new Map();
if(connectedClients.has("1")) {
    var socketInformation = connectedClients.get("1") // for userID 1
    var socketID = socketInformation.client.id
    io.sockets.connected[socketID].emit('message', req.query.message)
}
```

Basically, connectedClients holds key:value pairs like `userID:socketID`.

What I want to do next, is send the message to all my followers when I post an update. So when I post an update, I add this to my MySQL database, but for the users who are online, I want to send the update in real time to their screen. How can I go about this?

I feel like I have three options:

- I iterate through all the connectedClients and check if they are followers of mine;
- I iterate through all my followers and check if they are in the map;
- I create a "room" for all followers of every user, and emit the message to this room.

But I feel like there should be a better way. Any suggestions?
Also, I am wondering if my map (connectedClients) is a great way to store the current connected devices.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `io.sockets.emit(...)`? I mean:

```
const wsServer = require('socket.io');

let io = wsServer(webSocketsPort);
io.sockets.emit('your-event', () => 'hello, clients!');
```

Comment: Wouldn’t that emit to all connected users? I only want to send to a specific number of users, the people who zre following my account (think of it as my followers on Instagram for example). So to a “group” of people, which I retrieve from my MySQL database

Comment: sorry, I understand you want to send to all online users

Comment: Since socket does not know who is following you.. you have to get each followers socket.id and emit them.. or you create a room. ( name Like 'room'+youruserid) Push followers into room. Then emit to room